# Generate one HTML from API based on the object key language and language of page

Tags: javascript, html, object, key

I have an API request and I'm generating a HTML content from its data using `.map();`.

The issue I'm facing is that in the array of objects I have keys that are showing content in one language or another. I need to display specific keys in mapped HTML based on the language of the page.

Example of object key: `keyAEN: 'content in EN'` for English or `keyAFR: 'contenu en français'` for French.

My way of solving this isn't the DRY-est and there's some repeating code.

Please check below existing code and let me know what would be a better solution in this case. I would like to avoid generating a long HTML because of different language content in the keys.

```
// Find page language in URL
const findUrl = window.location.href;

const regex = /\.eu\/(\w{2})\//;
const match = regex.exec(findUrl);

const resultLangUrl = match && match[1];
let pageLang = resultLangUrl.toUpperCase();

let language = pageLang.includes("EN");
let pickContainer = document.querySelector('#container');

// deleting keys not coresponding to page language from the objects
//ex: page language is EN, delete all FR keys
if (pageLang === true) {
    data.forEach(object => {
        delete object['KeyAFR']
        delete object['KeyBFR']
        delete object['KeyCFR']
    });

    //generate html for EN
    const generateHtmlEN = data.map(test => {
        return `<p>${test.KeyAEN}</p>
                <p>${test.KeyBEN}</p>
                <p>${test.KeyCEN}</p>`
    }).join('');

    pickContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', generateHtmlEN);

} else {
    data.forEach(object => {
        delete object['KeyAEN']
        delete object['KeyBEN']
        delete object['KeyCEN']
    });

    //generate html for FR
    const generateHtmlFR = data.map(test => {
        return `<p>${test.KeyAFR}</p>
                <p>${test.KeyBFR}</p>
                <p>${test.KeyCFR}</p>`
    }).join('');

    pickContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', generateHtmlFR);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to delete the keys you're not using. Because of the naming scheme, you can't really "for loop" this without "eval", which you probably want to avoid. Is there anyway you could name the keys `test[fr][a]` instead of `test.KeyAFR` (hash/object) instead.

Comment: @BarryCarter The keys coming from the REST API are looking like
`
0:
UserFromRegionEN: "Some region"
UserFromRegionFR: "Foreign text in FR"
`
Would be there a possibility to rename them before using in generated HTML?

Comment: It'd be nice if it was `UserFromRegion: FR`, but I guess you're stuck. You might be able to hack a JS solution using regexs, but still ugly.